# Efficient way to manage a git repository for local config files

Tags: git, config

I store my config files (`~/.bashrc`, `~/.emacs`, `~/emacs`, etc.) in git. The way I configured this was simply to add a git repository in the home dir.

I found this approach has some problems:

- `git gui` takes forever, because it recursively scans the whole home dir.
- I sometimes accidentally add files to the config repo that should go to a new repo (I create a new project, say in `~/projects/foo`, forget it doesn't yet have a git repo initialized, and execute `git add bar.xyz` in the `foo` directory. This results in a file being added to the config repo).

I'm not sure it is wise to have git repositories nested under a directory that already has a git repository, although I haven't yet encounter any fundamental problems with this.

Is there a better approach, or is this a standard way in which people store local config files in git?

Comment: If you're doing this to sync the files between machines, I'd just use Dropbox. If you want `git`, the setup will be analogous though: have a some directory with the sources somewhere (e.g. `~/Dropbox/home`, and have a skeleton `~/.bashrc` that sources `~/Dropbox/home/.bashrc` and symlinks the other files into `~`.

Comment: There are a lot of tools for this. See https://dotfiles.github.io/ under "General-purpose dotfile utilities".

Answer (score 3):

I am using a git repo to manage the dotfiles. It contains:

1. a directory `dotfiles`, which contains the actual dotfiles/dotdirs I want to track.
2. a shell script, to create symbolic link of `dotfiles/.*` in `$HOME`, like

   ```
   for dotfile in dotfiles/.* ; do
     case $(basename $dotfile) in
       .)
         ;;
       ..)
         ;;
       *)
         ln -sv $(realpath dotfile) $HOME/$(basename $dotfile)
         ;;
     esac
   done
   ```

The script is manually runned after I add something new in `dotfiles`(normally by moving a dotfile into repo), or in a new and clean `$HOME`.

The repo can reside anywhere. I have a clone in `$HOME` on each host I am using.

In this way I have a much smaller and non-nested work tree, to track the dotfiles selectively.

p.s. You may want to add entries like `dotfiles/.config/*` to `.gitignore`, it contains many files I don't want to track.

Comment: I like this idea, but some of the commands in that shell script are not available by default (ex: OSX doesn't have realpath).

Comment: Question: I do this, but I wonder how do you handle machine-specific variations? For example on my home computer I want my gitconfig email to be my personal email, but on my work computer I want it to be my work email, etc. Currently I handle this by copying certain files out of dotfiles to my ```$HOME``` but that becomes a maintenance nightmare (if I want to add a new git alias I have to update two .gitconfig files, etc).

Comment: @AdamParkin Per-machine settings distrub me as well (`.asoundrc`). As of git author, I use a zsh `cd` hook to set author per repo from path, see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jokester/208147bf83f155e1f39c6734a108feaa).  Haven't tried but global git hooks may be able to do something similar.

Answer (score 3):

I keep my dotfiles in a Git repository like you do—my home dir is a Git repository.

- `git gui`:  I rarely use it, so I'm not really sure how its performance is impacted by lots of untracked files.  However, I do have a `~/.gitignore` file that simply contains `*`.  Perhaps ignoring everything will speed up `git gui` for you.
- Accidentally adding files:  Creating a `~/.gitignore` file that simply contains `*` also solves the problem of accidentally adding a file to your dotfiles repository when you forget to initialize a new project repository (it'll tell you to use `-f` if you really want to add the file).
- I've never had a problem with nested repositories.

Some notes:

- The main reason why I set my `~/.gitignore` to `*` is so that `git status` doesn't show every file in my home directory.  It forces me to use `git add -f` all the time, which is a bit annoying, but not that big of a deal.
- Get in the habit of using `git clean -dx` instead of `git clean -dxf`.  You'll have to remember to run `git config clean.requireForce false` in new project repositories, but it'll prevent you from accidentally deleting all of your files in your home directory if you're not in the directory you think you're in.
- Git sometimes decides to reset file permissions.  This can be bad if you want to keep sensitive files (`chmod og-rwx`) in your Git repository.  I handle this via a `post-checkout` hook that fixes permissions of certain files and directories (e.g., `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`).