# Managing local config files with SVN

Tags: svn

My question is essentially [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082038/efficient-way-to-manage-a-git-repository-for-local-config-files), but for SVN.

I've got local configuration files that wouldn't necessarily make sense for other users to get. I have enough of these configuration files now that it would be a pain if I lost them all. It would be very helpful to have them linked to versions of the code since the config files occasionally change as the code evolves.

As one specific example, the makefile for my project occasionally changes but contains many path-specific options. I'd like to add this file to the repo so that it is automatically synced when *I* update, but not when other users update.

I've seen these questions [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189684/manage-config-file-differences-between-development-and-production-servers-with-s) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189684/manage-config-file-differences-between-development-and-production-servers-with-s), but they deal with files that should be on multiple servers. My question is instead about using SVN as a *synchronized*, *personal*, *backup*.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to add a pre-commit hook which will work only on the configuration files. You can make an operation in the code which will restrict the commit if the author of the operation is not you.
Hope this helps

Comment: Could you explain a little more how I can do that? I'm not sure what a "pre-commit hook" is, nor what "make an operation in the code" means. Thanks.

Comment: Check in your repository's hooks folder. You will find pre-commit file.
You may edit the same and put a check in it saying if the path of file is matching a specific path defined by you here, then only the id with specific permission should be allowed to commit or only if the author is matching your id then it should be allowed to commit